# Django equivalent for latest entry for each user

Tags: django

I'm surprised this question hasn't come up. Couldn't find much on the web.

Using `Entry.objects.latest('created_at')` I can recover the latest entry for all Entry objects, but say if I want the latest entry for each user? This is something similar to an SQL latest record query. But how do I achieve this using the ORM? Here is my approach I'm wondering if it is the most efficient way to do what I want.

First I perform a sub query: Objects are grouped by user and the Max (latest) created_by field is returned for each user (created_at__max) I then filter Entry objects based on the results in the subquery and get the required objects.

```
Entry.objects.filter(created_at__in=Entry.objects.values('user').annotate(Max('created_at')).values_list('created_at__max'))
```

or using a manager:

```
class UsersLatest(models.Manager):  

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(UsersLatest,self).get_query_set().filter(created_at__in=self.model.objects.values('user').annotate(Max('created_at')).values_list('created_at__max'))
```

Is there a more efficient way? possibly without sub query?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: I was toying with the idea of adding an is_latest boolean to my model, which I set when I save a new entry in my form.save method, I then recover the previous is_latest object and make it false---so there are two steps to each entry save. I don't know if this is the best way to go. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

Using [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) and [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

```
Entry.objects.all().order_by('user', 'created_at').distinct('user')
```

Then for performance adding index together on 'user' and 'created_at' fields.

But i think real production way is to use `Redis` to cache and update an id's list of latest entries of users.

Comment: This way doesn't support in MySQL @omid-raha

Answer (score 2):

The design of your QuerySet depends on what you plan to use it for. I'm not sure why you're breaking out of the QuerySet iterator with the values_list method at the end. I imagine you have a status list of users where you show the last activity time based on that Entries model. For that you may want to try this:

```
Users.objects.all().annotate(latest_activity=Max('entries__created_at'))
```

And then loop through your users easily in your template with

```
{% for user in users %}
{{ user.full_name }}
{{ user.latest_activity|date: "m/d/Y" }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, nice approach.

annotate(Max('created_at')) returns a list of dictionaries containing 'user' and 'created_at__max' data, I use values_list('created_at__max') to filter the data into a list for use with created_at__in=

Answer (score 1):

The raw SQL would be

```
SELECT entry.id, entry.title, entry.content, entry.user_id, entry.created_at
FROM
    entry
WHERE
    entry.created_at = ( SELECT Max(e2.created_at) from entry as e2 where e2.user_id = entry.user_id )
```

So one option is using the `where` argument of the [`extra()` modifier](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none):

```
Entry.objects.extra(where='entry.created_at = ( SELECT Max(e2.created_at) from entry as e2 where e2.user_id = entry.user_id )')
```

Of course, you'd probably have to change `entry` to whatever the actual name of the table is in the database. Assuming you're comfortable looking at `._meta`, you can try this:

```
Entry.objects.extra( where=
    '%(table)s.created_at = ( SELECT Max(e2.created_at) from %(table)s as e2 where e2.user_id = %(table)s.user_id )' % { 'table':Entry._meta.db_table }
)
```

There's probably a more elegant way to get the name of a table.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, does exactly what I require. 
I checked the sql of my Django query using ._as_sql() and it's almost exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and did it this way:

```
priorities = obj.books_set.values('category').annotate(priority=Max('priority'))
```

**Note:** I annotate max priority as priority, because I'll reuse the output as filter condition.

It's a list of categories with min priorities. Then I do this:

```
>>> priorities[0]
{'category': 1, 'priority': 10}
```

I want to find books that have category & priority pair among one in the list. In the end the queryset condition should look like this:

```
Q(priorities[0]) | Q(priorities[1]) | ...
```

To do this in one line, use `reduce` on `Q.__or__`:

```
reduce(Q.__or__, (Q(**x) for x in priorities))
```

I know it's a bit worse than raw SQL, but safer. Comment this code if you use it, because it's hard to read.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot think out a single raw sql query which will fetch the set you need, so I doubt it's possible to construct a QuerySet with these results.